# Parallel task execution on NAnt

Tags: nant

I am using NAnt to build 5 different installer packages for the same software, in different configurations. These tasks can be parallelized as they are not dependent on each other. Installshield which is building these configuration seems inefficient with regards to multi core CPU usage (the usage capped at 25% CPU on a 4 core machine). I have been looking for an easy way to parallize tasks and only found [this](http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=101), which is pretty much what I need. However the source code for this project is not available and it's referencing some types which are not available in the latest version of NAnt 0.91 which we require for .NET 4.0 support.

Any ideas on how to solve this, short of writing my own extension for NAnt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually found the source code by writing to the author. It's now a part of a project colled CIFactory and the source code can be accessed through the [project homepage](http://code.google.com/p/ci-factory/). With a few modifications I was able to get it running on the latest NAnt version. I will publish it when I work out a few kinks, mostly regarding where the output is streamed to.

Comment: Current source code seem to be at http://code.google.com/p/ci-factory/source/browse/Current/Product/Production/Nant/CIFactory.NAnt.Tasks/Tasks/

Answer (score 3):

If you look back on the page, further down in the comments
[Links to source code](http://www.jayflowers.com/Misc%20Downloads/Async.Tasks.zip)

The source is available. 'course reflector would dissassemble with the right plugin...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly difficult quite honestly, but I don't know of any other ready-made project or contrib task for NAnt that will do it. So your only option is pretty much to write your own parallel task implementation. That said, since the guy provides compiled assemblies, you could always give them a look-see in Reflector and get the general idea, if you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/NAntCrossCompile/NAnt.Parallel
There is a plugin in development which allows the parallel execution of tasks based on sets of files, folders, strings...

Comment: That link is dead.