# NAnt: parallel threads for execution of tasks; does this exist?

Tags: nant

I am looking an ability to execute `<tasks>` on separate threads, with the ability to join those separate threads after execution is done... does such a thing exist within any version of NAnt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258979/parallel-task-execution-on-nant

Answer (score 1):

From the comments: [Parallel task execution on NAnt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5258979/parallel-task-execution-on-nant/5309197#5309197) links to http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=101

... and answering in a comment is bad form.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131515/many-questions-answered-via-comment-instead-of-answer#comment362688_131515