# Running multiple tasks in parallel with NAnt

Tags: nant

I am trying to run multiple task in parallel to reduce time for my builds. But it seems like tasks are executing one after another sequentially. This is taking too much time for my builds. Is there any way to run multiple tasks in parallel in NAnt?

Comment: I doubt NAnt can handle this scenario. You can try creating a custom NAnt task, which is to do the job of parallel execution, but it sounds like a lot of work...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this has been asked before. See [NAnt: parallel threads for execution of tasks; does this exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711902/nant-parallel-threads-for-execution-of-tasks-does-this-exist)

Not the best question/answer, since the answer was moved out of a comment, which links to a blog that does have code.  See [AsyncExec and WaitForExit Speeding Up The Build To Do More](http://jayflowers.com/WordPress/?p=101)

Even that only gets to the example of how to use the code at [Async Tasks zip file](http://www.jayflowers.com/Misc%20Downloads/Async.Tasks.zip)

I have not used the code, but was searching NAnt.  I had only used the parallelism of multiple build machines.

Comment: The code is very old but helpful. I'd check if this can work of the shelf with the latest version or would need modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://github.com/NAntCrossCompile/NAnt.Parallel There is a plugin in development which allows the parallel execution of tasks based on sets of files, folders, strings...